# Errors in the RingCT 3.0 paper

Tags: signature

I found some errors in the RingCT 3.0 paper (https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/508.pdf) in the ring signature chapter.
This makes it impossible to implement this algorithm.

Namely:

1. In the chapter “*C.2 Ring Signature with Logarithm Size*”/”*Challenge 2*” was defined:
   `x = H5(v, w, y, z, T1, T2, m)`
   At that, the variable **v** is not defined anywhere else in the text.
2. In the chapter “*C.2 Ring Signature with Logarithm Size*”/”*Challenge 1*” was defined:
   `str′ = Y ||B||A|| S1||S2||U`
   At that, the variable **U** also is not defined anywhere else in the text.

Perhaps someone can clarify the situation.

Comment: No link of the paper, no $LaTeX/MathJax$.

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/508.pdf

Comment: Have you considered emailing the authors?

Comment: @Meaher Yes. I wrote to the authors. But the answer has not yet received. In addition, I think that clarification of these issues may be of interest not only to me.